# Why was this text removed from my question text?

Tags: discussion

Why was a phrase removed from my question on Stack Overflow?

That phrase is this:

> when I check my check box I call a javascript function that calls the CallbackPanel.PerformCallback() function and this function does what it does. anyway if it's getting perplexing let me illuminate you:

And it was changed to:

> When I check my check box I call a JavaScript function that calls the CallbackPanel.PerformCallback() function and this function does what it does.

Why was "Let me illuminate you" dropped?

Comment: Probably because its uneccessary fluff that does not add anything to the question, and because its odd to say "let me illuminate you" when you mean "I will explain it".

Comment: It's unnecessary information to the question

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can click the "edited 4 hours ago" link under your question to see the [revision history of your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/39056986/revisions). There you can also see the comment entered for that edit:

> Fix case, punctuation, trim chat and help begging

Someone edited your question and removed that phrase, amongst other edits, to make it sound clearer and more to the point.